# How to display query assembled by ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, kohana

How to display query assembled by ORM ?

Example: SELECT `article`.`id` AS `article:id`, `article`.`name` AS `article:name`

I'm using the code below:

```
$query=DB::select('categories.*', 
                    array(DB::expr('COUNT(categories.id)'), 'total'),
                    array(DB::expr('MIN(displays.price)'), 'min_price'),
                    array(DB::expr('MAX(displays.price)'), 'max_price'),
                    array(DB::expr('SUM(displays.is_offer)'), 'is_offer')
            )
            ->from('categories')
                ->join('category_products', 'INNER')
                ->on('categories.id', '=', 'category_products.category_id')
                ->join('displays', 'INNER')
                ->on('category_products.product_id', '=', 'displays.product_id')
            ->where('displays.active', '>=', 1)
            ->group_by('categories.id')
            ->order_by('parent')
            ->order_by('total', 'desc');
```

Comment: At least you know you are using Kohana! http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, you're using [`DB::select()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/DB#select) which returns a [`Database_Query_Builder_Select`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select) instance. In the doc it says

> Database query builder for SELECT statements. See [Query Builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide//database/query/builder) for usage and examples.

And if you do see, you'll see

```php
echo Debug::vars((string) $query);
// Should display:
// SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'john'
```

which makes sense once you see the [`__toString()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select#__toString) from `Database_Query_Builder_Select`.

So

```php
echo (string) $query;
```

should give you the query.

Comment: Thanks @kingkero
WHAT exactly I wanted.